# Bind wpf listbox to ObservableCollection of tuples

Tags: c#, wpf

I have created  `ObservableCollection<Tuple<string,string>> servers;` 
every tuple contains two fields 
Is it possible to bind this collection to listBox - so, that after binding there are only name strings in this listBox?

the Name String - is the first string from the tuple

```
private ObservableCollection<Tuple<string,string>> nameVals;

 public ObservableCollection<Tuple<string,string>> NameVals
        {
            get
            {
                if (nameVals == null)
                     nameVals= new ObservableCollection<Tuple<string, string>>(Helpers.getNamesAndValues("ololo"));
                return nameVals;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Please clarify your question. What "name strings" are you referring to? Can you provide an example of something you've tried?

Comment: Can you please provide us with more code and a question so that we can help you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can bind the ItemsSource of your ListBox to your ObservableCollection (!must be a property) and set `DisplayMemberPath="Item1"` on the ListBox.